# Include external .dll with XAP file when submit App to Windows Phone store?

Tags: c#, dll, json.net, external

I use Json.net library in my project, so what do I do when submit App to Windows Phone store? Do I have to include .dll lib (of Json.net), or just submit the .XAP file?
Thank you.

Comment: just submit the xap file, assuming the project has a reference to JSON.net

Answer (score 0):

I found out, all the external dlls are encapsuled in the XAP file. Just submit the XAP file.